# How can i replace the DOM in $(this) with another DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML Content like below

```
<div class="form-field">
     <div style="width: auto; display: inline-block; min-width: 108px;" class="form-field-header">
      <div class="form-field-header-caption">facility</div>
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block;" class="form-field-body">
      <input class="form-field-required" readonly="" maxlength="20" value="" type="text" data-binding-view-property="Value" data-binding-model-object="inwork" data-binding-model-property="fac">
       <textboxcontrol class="form-field-required" data-binding-view-property="Value" maxlength="20" data-binding-model-object="inwork" data-binding-model-property="fac"></textboxcontrol>
       </div>
  </div>
```

For the above HTML content I am writing a jQuery code to substitute a DOM element that will be given by the plugin. The jQuery script is as below

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".form-field").find('textboxcontrol').each(function () {
        var options = {
            "attributeName": 'test',
            "defaultValue": "",
            "isViewonly": 0,
            "isReadOnly": 0,
            "filterAttribute": 0
        };
        field = $.fn.textBoxControl(options);
        $(this).replaceWith(field);
    });
});
```

`field` variable will have data something like

```
<input class="textboxControl" maxLength="2147483647" value="" type="text">
```

as a DOM ( i.e - `field[0].outerHTML` in firebug DOM )

`$(this)` - will have the tag selected from HTML content. The above written code is replacing the DOM. Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Is `.replaceWith()` definitely not working? Are you getting any error messages in your browser's console?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here - what is not working as desired?

Comment: The user defined tag ( i.e - <textboxcontrol> ) should be replaced with the DOM that is returned by the plugin $.fn.textBoxControl(options)

Comment: Would you be able to tell us exactly what `$.fn.textBoxControl(options);` returns?

Comment: returns a DOM as mentioned in the above explanation. <input class="textboxControl" maxLength="2147483647" value="" type="text">

Answer (score 1):

Came out with a solution of replacing the line with this solution.`$(this).replaceWith(field[0].outerHTML)` Anyways Thanks everyone.